# Xarray: Filtering on float

Tags: python, pandas, python-xarray

This subject refers to this one I closed earlier:
[NetCDF4 file with Python - Filter before dataframing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75094538/netcdf4-file-with-python-filter-before-dataframing/75094747#75094747)

After applying the solution of the other topic to reduce an xarray size

```
data_9 = ds.sel(time=datetime.time(9))
```

I have an xarray this way:

[image]

But I still can and need to reduce it on latitude and longitude
For example I want only longitude between -4 and 44

I tried to apply the function sel again but it doesn't seem to work this time :'(

```
data_9 = ds.sel(time=datetime.time(9)).sel(lon>-4).sel(lon<44)
```

Doing this it can't recognise lon...

```
NameError: name 'lon' is not defined
```

Can someone helps on this too?
Thanks

Comment: Can you try with the name of your DataArray in the front of "lon"? `.sel(-4 < ds.lon < 44`).

Comment: Thanks for replying. Doing so I have an new issue: "ValueError: the first argument to .sel must be a dictionary"

Answer (score 0):

It seems you have to use [`where`](https://xarray.pydata.org/en/v2022.12.0/generated/xarray.Dataset.where.html) instead of `sel` here. We can create a condition array just like in numpy and give it to `where`. The second parameter `drop=True` removes the data where our condition is falsy. Without it, you would get `nan`s there instead of getting a trimmed dataset.

I am using the same demo dataset used in the other question you linked.

```
import xarray as xr
import datetime

# Load a demo dataset.
ds = xr.tutorial.load_dataset('air_temperature')

data_9 = ds.sel(time=datetime.time(9))
cond = (-4 < data_9.lon) & (data_9.lon < 44)
data_9 = data_9.where(cond, drop=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

Xarray's `sel` methods can take multiple selectors and windows in the form of slices:

```
ds_subset = ds.sel(time=datetime.time(9), lon=slice(-4, 44))
```